# autohotkey web scraping code optimization

Tags: autohotkey

I added my scraping code below, I would in theory, start on a page with 25 values for me to pull, and appends the way I want it too.

Some pages have less than 25 and gives me error's and blank lines on my .txt. Can smarter minds help me clean this up?

Here is the scraping code for me to use for another area that is working fine.

```
F3::Loop_Scrape()
Loop_Scrape() {
If ErrorLevel 
    return
else
prop_1=,prop_2=,prop_3=,prop_4=,prop_5=,prop_6=,prop_7=,prop_8=,prop_9=,prop_10=,prop_11=,prop_12=,prop_13=,prop_14=,prop_15=,prop_16=,prop_17=,prop_18=,prop_19=,prop_20=,prop_21=,prop_22=,prop_23=,prop_24=,prop_25=
Sleep,150
    IfWinExist,ahk_class IEFrame
    {
        pwb:=WBGet()
        WinActivate
    }
Sleep,350
    prop_1:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[1].innerText
    prop_2:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[12].innerText
    prop_3:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[23].innerText
    prop_4:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[34].innerText
    prop_5:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[45].innerText
    prop_6:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[56].innerText
    prop_7:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[67].innerText
    prop_8:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[78].innerText
    prop_9:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[89].innerText
    prop_10:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[100].innerText
    prop_11:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[111].innerText
    prop_12:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[122].innerText
    prop_13:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[133].innerText
    prop_14:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[144].innerText
    prop_15:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[155].innerText
    prop_16:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[166].innerText
    prop_17:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[177].innerText
    prop_18:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[188].innerText
    prop_19:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[199].innerText
    prop_20:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[210].innerText
    prop_21:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[221].innerText
    prop_22:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[232].innerText
    prop_23:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[243].innerText
    prop_24:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[254].innerText
    prop_25:=pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[265].innerText
Sleep,350
FileAppend,%prop_1%`n%prop_2%`n%prop_3%`n%prop_4%`n%prop_5%`n%prop_6%`n%prop_7%`n%prop_8%`n%prop_9%`n%prop_10%`n%prop_11%`n%prop_12%`n%prop_13%`n%prop_14%`n%prop_15%`n%prop_16%`n%prop_17%`n%prop_18%`n%prop_19%`n%prop_20%`n%prop_21%`n%prop_22%`n%prop_23%`n%prop_24%`n%prop_25%`n,Docs/MyFile2.txt
return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dude you should try creating a dict

here's my python version of what you should do hope it helps

```
props = {}#Create dictionary 
index = 1 #index of the elements 
for i in range(1,26): #goes from 1-25
    #getting the element and put it in the dictionary 
    props['prop'+str(i)] = pwb.document.GetElementsByTagName("TD")[index].innerText
    #incrementing the index
    index +=11

for key, value in props.iteritems():
    if value != "":
        file.append(value)
```

sorry i dont know c++ i just saw your question but if you get the idea you can make it

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, unfortunately I have no idea how to convert that to C++ or AHK but the structure is exactly what I want so i'm doing research.